# iOS development on non-Mac

Tags: ios, windows, ubuntu

What is technical reason(compiling,formatting stuff etc) why you can't build iOS apps on Windows/Ubuntu with objective-c(just build it and upload it to your own iPhone, not app store)?

Comment: I don't think there's an actual technical reason, except that Apple don't want to support it and writing and maintaining the cross compilers, simulator and libraries is a lot of work. Same reason you write Windows Phone 7 Apps using Windows and Visual Studio. It's not that it's technically impossible, it's just bas business for them to waste resources supporting it.

Comment: IIRC, there was/is a gcc-based toolchain that ran on a modified OS iOS device itself which could build runnable apps, so there is no technical reason why one could not build iOS apps on those devices capable of running a modified non-stock OS, without a Mac.

Comment: I too remember developing, and emulating app for iPad an iPhone in c++ on Windows during some devmeeting. Unfortunately I can't remember the emulator' name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason, only business reasons. There once were cross-compiling tool chains to do rudimentary iOS development on Windows (and, AFAIK, Linux) but they aren't actively developed any more since it's a lot of work with no real benefit.

The business reason is pretty clear: Apple wants you to work on a Mac. If you don't have one but you want to develop for iOS then Apple wants you to buy one. It makes sense for them to provide iTunes for Windows since they make money with the content, but it doesn't make any sense at all for Apple to provide their development platform on any other OS than Mac OS X: it would increase the complexity of the whole development toolchain and overall would require a lot of additional work and thus would cost a lot of money. Plus, the support team would suddenly have to deal with people using an "alien" OS (Windows), also costing money. Apple is pretty quick to abandon what they consider old technologies: the current (early 2012) Xcode is only supported on their very latest OS, Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. On Windows, where the ancient XP is still used widely, they couldn't do that. This would bind additional resources and thus cost even more money (and might taint the experience/feature set).

All these additional costs cannot be reasonably justified. Especially for the very first point: Apple wants you to buy a Mac. Chances are that you might stick as a customer and thus make even more money for Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The technical reason is the binary you create won't be built for either the right hardware or the right operating system. There's far more to making a program written in some language work beyond just having a compiler for that language.

Comment: cross compilers are possible...

Comment: @crashmstr of course they're possible. Do you know of any for the iPhone? Until someone with the necessary details creates one and releases it, it might as well be considered impossible.

Comment: I would argue that the *practical* reasons are lack of tool-chain. I would concede that there *might* be some technical reasons in the implementation (done by Apple or by others), but certainly nothing that obvious.

Comment: There were cross-compiling tool chains available (for example, [iphone-dev](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/)) but they are all (AFAIK) abandoned. Technically, it's not hard to do these cross-compiling frameworks (I know since I've done a few for Linux), but it's a lot of work and requires constant maintenance. Basically, every new iOS release from Apple would require you to adapt the cross-compiling toolchain. And simply nobody wants to do that any more.